# Angular momentum - Question on Zare's use of the Vector Model to Estimate Probability

Tags: quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

My question regards a specific example, although I get the feeling that the answer is simpler than I imagine. In Zare's *Angular Momentum: Understanding Spatial Aspects in Chemistry and Physics pgs 53-54*, He discusses the vector model for coupled and uncoupled representations for the addition of two angular momenta.

I've scanned and included the picture I am going to refer to for clarity:

[image: Fig. 1]
The image above is a modified representation of the ***uncoupled representation***, although it appears very similar to the coupled diagram, the difference is that **j1** has been arbitrarily fixed, and **j2** is precessing in the dashed circle, around an axis parallel to z.

Zare expands the dot product of $\mathbf{j_1}$ and $\mathbf{j_2}$
(Eq 2.34):

$\mathbf{j_1 . j_2} = |\mathbf{j_1}||\mathbf{j_2}| cos(\gamma)$

$=|\mathbf{j_1}||\mathbf{j_2}| [ cos(\theta_1) cos(\theta_2)+  sin(\theta_1) sin(\theta_2) cos(\theta_1) cos(\phi_1 -\phi_2)]$

So far, so good, no problem. Then he instructs:

"Let us differentiate Eq (2.34) with respect to time to obtain the rate of change of the length of $\mathbf{j}$. From the law of cosines

$|\mathbf{j}|^2 = |\mathbf{j_1}|^2 + |\mathbf{j_2}|^2 - 2 |\mathbf{j_1}| |\mathbf{j_2}| cos(\gamma)$

$=|\mathbf{j_1}|^2 + |\mathbf{j_2}|^2 - 2 \mathbf{j_1} . \mathbf{j_2}$

So that

$\frac d{dt} (\mathbf{j_1} . \mathbf{j_2}) = -\frac 12 \frac d{dt} [ |\mathbf{j}|^2 + |\mathbf{j_1}|^2 - |\mathbf{j_2}|^2 ]$"

And **THIS** next step is where I get lost:

He ***IMMEDIATELY*** equates that expression with the following:

$$ = -|\mathbf{j}| \frac {d|\mathbf{j}|}{dt} $$

So that there's no confusion, what I do not understand is the statement:

$$\frac d{dt} (\mathbf{j_1} . \mathbf{j_2}) = -\frac 12 \frac d{dt} [ |\mathbf{j}|^2 + |\mathbf{j_1}|^2 - |\mathbf{j_2}|^2 ] = -|\mathbf{j}| \frac {d|\mathbf{j}|}{dt}$$

---

Now, if I explicitly expand all components of the vector norms: $\mathbf{j_1}$,$\mathbf{j_2}$,and $\mathbf{j}$, and try to solve for what's inside the brackets on the LHS, I just regenerate the expression:

$|\mathbf{j}|^2 =|\mathbf{j_1}|^2 + |\mathbf{j_2}|^2 - 2 \mathbf{j_1} . \mathbf{j_2}$, which is of no use in aiding me as far as I can see.

Furthermore, it is explicitly stated that the only time-dependent component of this system is the dihedral angle $\phi_1 - \phi_2$, and in any expansion of the vector $|\mathbf{j}|$ into its components, a time derivative would render the any other independent parts mute.

I am thoroughly confused. I have consulted the following textbooks and not found any sign of this exact derivation:

*Cohen-Tannoudji (volumes I and II), Feynman's lectures on Physics Vol III, Shankar, Atkin's physical chemistry, Engel and Reid's physical chemistry, Gaziorowicz, and Eisberg and Resnick.*

What I suspect is that I'm simply lacking in some fundamental piece of calculus or arithmetic. Whether there's some simple trick of Vector Calculus that I haven't employed to give me the identity placed here? I would love a direct answer, but will also accept a nudge in the right direction. Right now it just feels like I'm leafing through books without a compass.

Best,

and ***THANKS!***

Comment: +1 for citing Dick Zare, a truly significant contributor to the field of chemical physics.

Comment: Nothing special here, just that the moduli of  $\mathbf j_1$ and $\mathbf j_2$ are fixed, by definition of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by Weijun Zhou, the length of the vectors $\mathbf{j}_1$ and $\mathbf{j}_2$ does not change as $\mathbf{j}_2$ precesses about $\mathbf{j}_1$, only the total vector $\mathbf{j}$ changes its length. Knowing this just requires application of the sum and chain rule of derivations that is

$
-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|\mathbf{j}|^2=-2|\mathbf{j}|\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|\mathbf{j}|
$

and the time derivatives of $\mathbf{j}_1$ and $\mathbf{j}_2$ are zero.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I expected it to be obvious. It's been a while since I've had to apply calculus to vectors.